# How to have UISearchController wait until search is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to implement the search in my SWIFT code. I want it to wait until the search button is clicked before it does anything. What I have so far.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    self.filteredCats.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    filteredCats = art.filter{
        $0.sarticleTitle.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) != nil
    }
        print(searchController.searchBar.text)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It prints out all the information once the user types something. I want it to wait till the search button is clicked or when the user has finished typing everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set delegate like this your view controller.

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("search button click")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_:)` [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarSearchButtonClicked:)

```
class MySearchController:UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    override init(searchResultsController: UIViewController?) {
        super.init(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        // Set the searchbar delegate
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        // Start the search
    }

}
```

Importantly, make sure you tell the `UISearchBar` that you want the `UISearchController` to be it's delegate, the above is an un-tested example, your exact initialisation may differ.

Answer (score 0):

implement "searchController.searchBar.delegate" & "searchBarSearchButtonClicked" method

```
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; 

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //enter your search code
}
```